# Debug HDMI over USB C

Tags: usb-connection-mode, motorola, hdmi

I have a Motorola Edge 20 Pro. Till about 8-9 months ago, I could connect an unpowered (Without a separate power adaptor) USB C Hub to the USB port, and connect a HDMI cable to the hub. This would allow me to use the phone as a media hub and project on the screen connected to the HDMI cable. I believe this was part of the "Ready for" feature

I have recently tried using this feature again, and it refuses to work. When I connect an unpowered USB hub to the phone, the "USB controlled by" settings go to read only mode as "Connected device" and I'm unable to use the hub in any manner. Connecting to a powered USB hub just charges the phone.

Trying to change the USB preferences to "This device" fails with an error message.

I have tried the following as of now:

1. Tried cleaning out the port
2. Tried with 2 different adapters
3. Tried with my work profile disabled
4. Tried safe mode

Looking for any other options to debug this issue and get HDMI out over USB C working